# Xamarin Forms - Master Detail Page - dynamically changing menu selection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin Forms and trying to figure out how to dynamically add buttons to the master detail page menu.

So far, In my view model I have a copy constructor that is getting passed a boolean and an optional object. Shown below

```
public partial class MainMasterDetailPageMaster : Content Page {

  public Main Master DetailPageMaster() 
  {
    Initialize Component() //yada yada
   }
...

  public class MainMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel : BaseViewModel 
 {

  private bool _contactButtonEnabled
  public bool ContactButtonEnabled {
  get {
  return _contactButtonEnabled;
    }
  set {
          if (!SetProperty(ref _contactButtonEnabled, value) 
        {
          _contactButtonEnabled = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("ContactButtonEnabled");
        }  
    }

// One Constructor that gets no arguments
  public MainMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel() 
  {
  //rest service connection
  }

// Copy Constructor that gets a boolean and an object
  public MainMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel(bool enabled, object content = null) 
  {
     // rest service conn

    // setting button visibility to true
    ContactButtonEnabled = true;
   }
 }
}
```

*Edit Added Here
In Select Views I'm changing the button to be visible

```
public class ContactView : ContentPage 
{

        public ContactView(Contact content) 
             {
              BindingContext = new ContactViewModel();
              var navViewModel = new MainMasterDetailPageMaster.MainMasterDetailPageMasterViewModel(true, content);                
              }
}
```

Using Breakpoints, I can tell that the copy constructor is being run at the right time and the boolean is being changed. However, the button is not showing after the boolean is changed to true.

Furthermore, I can tell that my binding is ostensibly correct since If I change it to true in my original constructor the button is clearly visible.

The only other thing that I can think of is needing to reset the Master? However, I'm unsure of how to do this specifically when my detail page has changed to a different view.

Could anyone offer some guidance on this issue? Thank you for any available help.

Comment: are you just trying to change the visibility of a button at runtime?  It sounds like you are using multiple instances of the VM - is that right?

Comment: I'm trying to change the visibility of button based on what view I'm on. However, your response makes me think that I should treat buttons as static? As for multiple VM's, no? (I'm not sure what that means tbh) I'm programming for cross platform but I am only using one Android Emulator for now.

Comment: VM means ViewModel.   You have multiple constructors for different scenarios, which makes me think that you are creating a new VM when you want to modify the visibility.  But I can't say for sure because you haven't posted enough code

Comment: Thanks for you help, sorry about the confusion. Yes, I am using multiple VM's. I will edit my code to try and show that.

Comment: that just doesn't work.  If your menu page is bound to an instance of a VM, then creating a new instance will not have any effect on that existing page.

Comment: first, please check the code that you're posting to be sure it is correct.  The edit you just made is not valid C# - there is a "." in the middle of a statement and no ";" on the last line.  It is very difficult to help debug code when it contains errors likes this.

Comment: second, are you just trying to disable/hide the current menu option?  ie, when they select "Contact" from the menu, you want to navigate to the Contact page and hide the Contact menu item?

Comment: Understood, I'm trying to enable a button "DeleteContactBtn" in the menu that will only appear visible when we have selected a contact in the view (via a list view).

Comment: that seems like an odd UX design to me.  ListView has a built in context menu you can use for deleting, or I would just put the button directly on the contact page so that it's readily visible to the user.  If you really want to have it on you master page, then you could use MessagingCenter to achieve that

Comment: Thank you for your help Jason. I'll probably go with the Delete button on the contact page idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach MainMasterDetailPageMaster object from MyMasterDetailPage like this

```
      MasterPage.vm.ContactButtonEnabled = false
```